# Does "in the following section" means only the next section?

Tags: expressions

I'm writing an academic paper. I'd like to say that I will discuss the details of this topic *later*.

How do I describe above in formal way?

I usually write like "as discussed in Section 3". However, sections do not have numbers at this time.

My idea is "as discussed in the following section". But I'm worry whether 'following' means only the next one. If the current section is "Section 1" and the details are discussed in "Section 3", can I still use 'following section'?

Comment: "**The** following section" always means the next-succeeding one; *the* is licensed because there can only be one next section. But you may write "in **a** following section" without specifying which section you mean.

Comment: You can also use "in a later section" or similar if there are multiple sections between the two.

Answer (score 2):

"Following" can mean any section that comes after the place the sentence is written, however when you add the definitive article "the" to make it "the following section" then you limit it to only the one section directly after where this is written.

If you want to refer to a later section (e.g. you're writing in section 1, about something which will be discussed in section 3), and you can't use the section number (or title) then you'd need to say "a following section".

Answer (score 0):

How about "the upcoming section"?

Comment: Wouldn't that still mean "the next section"?

Comment: Hi welcome to ELL! We expect our answers to be detailed and explanatory. Could you write a bit more why your suggestion works in the context given?